# Con't import video in nextJs in simple way

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, frontend, web-deployment

[Code Of import coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX3YY.png)

[After the import code i facing this error, no any resources available in internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9PGz.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your import video and put your public video src to video atribute

```
Remove this => import video from "../public/video/background-1.mp4"

<video playsInline muted autoPlay src="../public/video/background-1.mp4" />
```

Comment: Removing the import will make the video not compiled, which is not 100% what kramchandra is asking here